# Is MessageListener object in JMS thread?

Tags: multithreading, jms, listener, message-listener

I'm writting a Java application for messaging between two or more clients. I'm using JMS (Java Messaging Service). For receiving message I wrote a `MessageListener` object that implements the `javax.jms.MessageListener` with `onMessage` method.

I'm wondering if the `MessageListener` object is some kind of background thread? I think it is a thread, because `MessageListener` receives and processes messages while my application is working on other things.

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help other users who have this same question in the future. If not, please elaborate as to why. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Every JMS provider implements their own JMS client so it's impossible to answer this question with 100% certainty without knowing what JMS client you're using, but in general the `onMessage` method of a `javax.jms.MessageListener` will be invoked in another thread in order to receive messages asynchronously as defined in the JMS specification.